Cannot perform sync due to error: trying to sync between different resource type
I am trying to sync text files from VM's folder to Azure Storage (Blob storage).
I have following command that I got from this YouTube video that I am using from command prompt on VM.
C:\Windows\System32>azcopy.exe sync "C:\AzCopyTest" "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/**SAS Token**" --delete-destination=true

When I ran the command, I got following error message:
INFO: Autologin not specified.
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Unknown, Please 
authenticate using Microsoft Entra ID 
(https://aka.ms/AzCopy/AuthZ), 
use AzCopy login, or append a SAS token to your Azure URL.

Cannot perform sync due to error: trying to sync between different 
resource types (either file <-> directory or directory <-> file) 
which is not allowed.sync must happen between source and 
destination of the same type, e.g. either file <-> file or 
directory <-> directory.
To make sure target is handled as a directory, add a trailing '/' 
to the target.

I have following folder structure in VM:

I set up a blog storage with a container like this:

What am I missing?
Update (10/16/2024):


Could you please tell me about your azcopy version?

The issue occurs mainly in 10.16.0 version and it solved in 10.17.0 version Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/1905

@Venkatesan I downloaded the "azcopy_windows_amd64_10.26.0"


Cannot perform sync due to error: trying to sync between different resource type.

In my environment, When I tried with same command with correct destination storage account URL + SAS token it executed successfully.
Command and Output:
PS C:\Windows\system32> azcopy sync "C:\Azcopytest" "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample/?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-08-30T12:32:33Z&st=2024-08-30T04:32:33Z&spr=https&sig=HVvJUuHrDuGxxxxx" --delete-destination=true
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job cc3107xxxxx04b9477e has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\v-vsettu\.azcopy\cxxxxxx9477e.log

INFO: Deleting extra object: TestData/29-08-2024.html
100.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0

Job ccxxxx969504b9477e Summary
Files Scanned at Source: 1
Files Scanned at Destination: 2
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.067
Number of Copy Transfers for Files: 0
Number of Copy Transfers for Folder Properties: 0
Total Number of Copy Transfers: 0
Number of Copy Transfers Completed: 0
Number of Copy Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Deletions at Destination: 1
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 0
Total Number of Bytes Enumerated: 0
Final Job Status: Completed

PS C:\Windows\system32> azcopy --version
azcopy version 10.26.0


I got the same error when I didn't pass the sas token with forward slash(/) in the destination endpoint.
Command and output:
PS C:\Windows\system32> azcopy sync "C:\Azcopytest" "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample" --delete-destination=true
INFO: Autologin not specified.
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Unknown, Please authenticate using Microsoft Entra ID (https://aka.ms/AzCopy/AuthZ), use AzCopy login, or append a SAS token to your Azure URL.

Cannot perform sync due to error: trying to sync between different resource types (either file <-> directory or directory <-> file) which is not allowed.sync must happen between source and destination of the same type, e.g. either file <-> file or directory <-> directory.To make sure target is handled as a directory, add a trailing '/' to the target.


Make sure you are using both Storage endpoint and SAS token in the destination URL is correct.
Reference:
azcopy sync | Microsoft Learn

I think the issue might be how I get the SAS token. I updated the original post with one more screenshot. As you can see, by default, when I go to "Shared access signature", it would not show SAS token right away. I had to click one of options in "Allowed resource types" to generate SAS token. I am not sure that is the reason because the error message mentioned about "destination".

I would like to follow up on my comment above. Do you have any reason why it is set up that way and is there any way to see the SAS token without clicking it? Thanks.

Raise it has new question with more in detail.

Sorry, I am not sure what you meant on your comment.

Create new question and add more details what you want with screen shots.
